# Colorbox loads all previous colorboxes

Tags: jquery, drupal, drupal-7, colorbox

I created a colorbox, and it works fine.  The problem is, when I close it, and open a different colorbox on the page, both colorboxes load (the first one directly behind the second).  When I close them, and open another one, I get three colorboxes, etc.

I'm doing this in a Drupal 7 view, I'm adding colorbox links to all the image fields.

My code for calling the colorboxes:

$('.views-field-field-gallery-images .field-content img').each(function() {

```
    nid = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.views-field-nid .field-content').html();
    href = $(this).attr('href');
    //$(this).attr('href', 'gallery-slideshow/' + nid +'?width=500&height=500&iframe=true');
    href = 'gallery-slideshow/' + nid;
    $(this).colorbox({href: href});
    //$(this).attr('href', 'http://www.cnn.com?width=500&height=500&iframe=true');
    //$(this).addClass('colorbox-load init-colorbox-load-processed cboxElement');
});
```

Comment: could you please describe why are using this code?

you can rewrite output in view itself to open this colorbox.

Please write down what functionality you need. Then I might help you  to get you the required result.

Answer (score 0):

use this in you colorbox:

```
var x = $(this).colorbox({onClosed: function(){ x.remove(); }});
```